# How do I return specific field of nested object array in angular having fields value?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an nested object array like this.

here is my array:

```
public collections: ICollections[] = [
  {
    collectionName: 'Brands',
    collectionFields: [
      {
        columnTitle : 'brandTitle',
        Type : dtEnum.string,
        control: {
          controlTitle: controlsEnum.input,
          controlType: controlsEnum.input,
          controlProperties: 
            {
              placeholder: 'Enter brand title here ...',
              type: 'text',
              autocomplete: false,
            }
        },
        columnWidth: 200
      }
    ],
    collectionFieldValidation: [{name: 'test'}],
    hasPaginator: true,
    stickyColumn: 0,
    stickyHeader: true
  },
    {
      columnTitle : 'brandURL',
      Type : dtEnum.string,
      control: {
        controlTitle: controlsEnum.input,
        controlType: controlsEnum.input,
        controlProperties: {
          placeHolder: 'Enter Brand URL',
          type: 'text',
          autocomplete: false,
        }
      },
      columnWidth: 300
    },
    {
      columnTitle : 'brandDescription',
      Type : dtEnum.string,
      control: {
        controlTitle: controlsEnum.textarea,
        controlType: controlsEnum.textarea,
        controlProperties: {
          placeHolder: 'Enter Brand Description',
          type: 'text',
          autocomplete: false,
        }
      },
      columnWidth: 300
    }
];
```

I want to reach to `placeholder` field. how do I find it by having only `collectionName` field with `Brands` value and `columnTitle` field with `brandURL` value ?

this question asked before just with `collectionName` field value but I find out that my filter should include more than one field.

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrbfrf

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Hi bro, I added some extra information to my question. would you please take a look again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
  placeholder_finder(collectionSearchKey: string, fieldSearchKey: string): string {
    let field: any;
    let placeholder: string;
    const obj = this.genInfo.collections.filter(
      x => x.collectionName === collectionSearchKey
    );
    obj.forEach(data => {
      field = data.collectionFields.filter(
        x => x.columnTitle === fieldSearchKey
      );
    });
    field.forEach(element => {
      placeholder = element.control.controlProperties.placeHolder;
    });
    return placeholder;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, find the collection that corresponds to "Brands" or any other thing:

```
let result = collections.find(p => p.collectionName === "Brands");
```

then get the `placeholder` field:

change `your_index` to 0 or your specific index

```
if (result) {
    let placeholder = result.collectionFields[your_index].control.controlProperties.placeholder;
}
```